# How to determine if the tangent of a value is rational or irrational?

Tags: trigonometry

How does one determine if the tangent of a value is rational or irrational, based on that value. For example, do rational values lead to rational outputs? Does irrationality not influence rationality of output? Is there a way to concretely determine this, based on the definition of an angle, and of tangent?

We know that sin(x) is irrational for non-zero rational inputs, but do we know that sin(x)/cos(x) is necessarily one way or the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider both $\tan(\pi/4)$ and $\tan(\pi/3)$.

Comment: If $x$ is a non-zero real algebraic number , $\sin(x)$ , $\cos(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ are all transcendental. This is a consequence of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem. For transcendental $x$ , the output can be anything : rational , irrational algebraic , transcendental.

Comment: Good to know, @Peter! And is there a way to determine which transcendental x have rational, which x have irrational algebraic, and which x have transcendental outputs?

Comment: In general , no. Of course rational multiples of $\pi$ can usually be decided.